# Ajax site. Page is correctly loaded depending on previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to ask your opinion. I'm building an ajax webpage. My links makes a GET of the URL they link to, pick the div.content and change the content of the actual div.content.

This GET action retrieves HTML code with some  code in it. It looks to execute propertly but only when I am not comming from an specific link. I don't see any sense.

I don't know which code may be useful to post here to see the effect, I apolozise if I am pasting to much or too less code.

I have these two function to manage the loading of new script resources in the main layout:

```
loadScript: function (scriptUrl, callback) {
    if (jsArray[scriptUrl]) {
        console.log("loadScript already loaded " + scriptUrl);
        callback && callback();
    } else {
        jsArray[scriptUrl] = true;
        console.log("loadScript " + scriptUrl);
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = scriptUrl;
        script.onload = callback;

        body.appendChild(script); //or something of the likes
    }
},
loadScripts: function (scriptsUrl, callback) {
    console.log("loadScripts");
    if (scriptsUrl.length === 1) {
        this.loadScript(scriptsUrl[0], callback);
    } else {
        var scriptUrl = scriptsUrl[0];
        scriptsUrl.shift();
        this.loadScript(scriptUrl, function () {
            Main.loadScripts(scriptsUrl, callback)
        });
    }
}
};
```

All my link with async class are binded to this function:

```
var loadAsyncUrl = function (url) {
    if (main.currentPage === url) {}
    main.currentPage = url;
    $("div.container .page-content").hide();
    $("div.container .loading-link").show();
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        $("div.container #page-header").html($(data).find("div.container #page-header").html());
        $("div.container .breadcrumb").html($(data).find("div.container .breadcrumb").html());
        $("div.container .content").html($(data).find("div.container .content").html());
        $("div.container .loading-link").hide();
        $("div.container .page-content").show();
    }, 'html')
        .fail(function (e) {
        alert("ERROR 404");
        console.log(e);
    });
};
```

If I go from the page A to any page (even the page A itself) the loadScripts call that there is at the bottom of div.content is not called. On the other hand, if I go from page B to any page, even A again, the code is executed correctly.

The page A, actually, has got HTML code a bit heavier than the other pages, with all the CSS rules, etc. that consume probably more time to render. May it be the reason? How do you explain if I load again page A coming from page A it is loading propertly?

How would you manage this? I would like that the links point to a complete webpage and not just the partial html I want to load. I want this because if the user decides to open in a new tab, they have the entire section.

Comment: did you get any error from the console?

Comment: I didn't. The problem is solved. How the JS is executed, even if it doesn't do what I was expecting, but this is another point... Thanks

Comment: hope my answer drives you in the correct way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dammed! Three days looking for it and it was in front of me.

I had more than div.content inside div.container in my page A.

Changed for unique id and working.

sorry

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your code I suspect that maybe in your page A some of this selectors is missing

1. `$("div.container #page-header")`
2. `$("div.container .breadcrumb")`
3. `$("div.container .content")`

try checking the `length` property of your objects

```
if ($("selector").length > 0){
   //replace html
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but no success... I have tried and nothing. Anyway, all the elements has content.

Comment: did you get any error from the console? If yes can you post it?